# Devtools audit shows unwanted/injected css rules

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, code-injection

So, in trying to debug the performance of a webpage in Chrome devtools, I found that my page has lengthy css rules that I did not put there. I cant see the rules when I view the source. But chrome tells me that the rules are being executed. The rules are also obviously malicious,

things like .yahoo-sponsored to [onclick^="window.open('http://

My question is how to find out what is, I am presuming, injecting this into my DOM?
I cant see anything when I view the source.

I am kind of at a loss as to how to proceed.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on a completely different computer? At least with another browser: Firefox, without JS? Seems like you've a malware or toolbar you didn't intend to install... EDIT: does it happen with pages from other sites? Are you using a CMS with plugins/extensions that would add these via obfuscated JS?

Comment: I can reproduce the slowness with IE, but I dont know of any tools to let me profile to see the css (I cant see the css in chrome either). I can also reproduce on another computer. I am not using a CMS, it is a struts2 app.

Comment: In Chrome: Inspect element and then Elements and Resources tabs let you see CSS or CSS files loaded. IE Developer Toolbar was a plugin for old IEs; just press F12 with IE9 or install Firebug light. No CMS so it isn't a WordPress plugin/theme of uncertain origin loading obfuscated JS, good. Did you clean your PC with a tool like CCleaner (on the subject I kept stuck 5 years ago ^^, there may have far better tools now)? Maybe you installed a toolbar without much knowing with Flash, Java, etc or Chrome if not downloaded from GG. Major DL sites install their own update thing and bam!... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are, most likely, injected by an extension similar to AdBlock, which injects an inline stylesheet with no textContent (which is rendered just as `<style></style>` in the DevTools) but rather dynamically adds required rules via the [CSSOM](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/) API.

To avoid seeing these rules in the audit results, disable AdBlock or a similar extension, reload the page, and run the audits once again.